# How to create map with own locations and give the nearest location to user according zip code they enter

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Ref link - http://suvn502study.com/find-a-study-center/

please help me. Thank you.

Comment: What you have tried yet in coding ?

Comment: i am very new to these types of concept. I already shared a reference link. Please have a look. Mayank pandeyz Suman dey

Comment: Why don't you take a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding cos this part of google map api